# How to resize / scaletype imageview on Android 8.0 Oreo?

Tags: imageview, android-8.0-oreo, scaletype

I have code to scaletype imageview and succesfully tried on Android 4, 5, 6, 7.

But on Oreo, my imageview cant change

I tested on Asus  Max Pro M1 Android 8.1

Example of my code below

```
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    iv2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer by myself hehe

My solution is change imageView height to equal with device height

If Zenfone max pro m1 display height is 2000 px, so I changed resolution of imageView height to 2000 px too

On my question, my imageView height is 1000 px, so there was nothing happen on Zenfon maxpro m1 when I used CENTER_CROP

Thanks ^_^